# Declaring @Model.item in MVC to use it in conditional statements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've created a controller and I'm trying to use razorview to check if an attribute is equal to zero.

My code is:

```
@model IEnumerable<SPIDSILIGA.Models.ApplicationUser>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Ekipa";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
item.FK_Team = 0; //This works
}
@if(Model.FK_Team == 0) // Doesn't work
{

}
```

How do I use the Model.attribute in an if statement?

Comment: The model in the view is `IEnumerable<T>` which does not have any properties. What in the world are you trying to do? - `if (item.FK_Team == 0 { // do something }` if you wanting a conditional statement

Comment: Nevermind, after like 6 or 7 hours of looking at code, I just got really confused. I fixed it.